# pivot_wider() does not collapse variables into single line

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

My dataset is like this

```
Organism    Reads    Name
Name1       10       MF60
Name2       100      MF60
Name1       50       MF60
Name2       75       AFM10
Name3       200      AFM10
```

When I use pivot_wider(),

```
df_wide <- df %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Organism, values_from = Reads)
```

I get output that looks like this

```
Name   Name1  Name2  Name3
MF60    10     NA     NA
MF60    NA     100    NA
MF60    NA     NA     50
AMF10   75     NA     NA
AMF10   NA     200    NA
etc..
```

Why isn't it collapsing all MF60 into a single row? I've tried changing the names_from and values_from values and it doesn't work. Thank you for any insight!

Comment: Based on your example,  it is collapsing for me

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of the input example you posted so that it is  easier to underrstand the structure i.e. `dput(df)`

Comment: It's a very big dataset. > dput(head(allBeetleFreqs))
structure(list(Organism = c("Unclassified", "Peptoniphilus methioninivorax", 
"Myroides odoratimimus", "Enterococcus sulfureus", "Peptoniphilus olsenii", 
"Dysgonomonas wimpennyi"), Reads = c(95345, 78055, 63769, 14849, 
14229, 13245), Percentage = c(28.95375, 23.70324, 19.36496, 4.509248, 
4.320971, 4.022156), Name = c("Marg F6O", "Marg F6O", "Marg F6O", 
"Marg F6O", "Marg F6O", "Marg F6O")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: ok, but based on your example, i cannot reproduce the output

Comment: I think I'm limited by size here. I don't know how to proceed. Can I attach a dataset?

Comment: Hundreds of rows are the same as MF60. There are >17,000 rows in the dataset.

Comment: ok, that explains, i  was thiinking that it is based on the e xample

Answer (score 4):

The problem is related to the extra Percentage column in your actual dataset that is not in your sample set above.  Since your dataset has an extra column that is not specified in the pivot_wider function, each row is treated uniquely and thus the incorrect square matrix.

If one excludes the extra column (Percentage) and selects only the desired columns (Organism, Reads and Name) the pivot_wider behaves as desired.

```
df-structure(list(Organism = c("Unclassified", "Peptoniphilus methioninivorax", "Myroides odoratimimus", "Enterococcus sulfureus", "Peptoniphilus olsenii", "Dysgonomonas wimpennyi"), 
      Reads = c(95345, 78055, 63769, 14849, 14229, 13245), 
      Percentage = c(28.95375, 23.70324, 19.36496, 4.509248, 4.320971, 4.022156),  
      Name = c("Marg F6O", "Marg F6O", "Marg F6O", "Marg F6O", "Marg F6O", "Marg F6O")), 
      row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyr)
df %>%  pivot_wider(names_from = Organism, values_from = Reads)
## Does not provide the desired Results!
```

**Working Version:**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(-Percentage) %>%  pivot_wider(names_from = Organism, values_from = Reads)

# # A tibble: 1 x 7
# Name   Unclassified `Peptoniphilus met~ `Myroides odorat~ `Enterococcus su~ `Peptoniphilus o~ `Dysgonomonas wi~
#   <chr>         <dbl>               <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>
#   1 Marg ~        95345               78055             63769             14849             14229
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and I solved it by dropping extra columns, so +1 to this answer!